# Got one error in my SelectionSort method that I cant figure out

Tags: java, algorithm

I tried to sort my arraylist with selectionsort instead of the Collection.sort and I think I got it right but it returns an error saying:

The method set(int, Bid) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)

here's the method, i wrote the error on the line it happened, cheers.

```java
    private ArrayList<Bid> sortBids() {

            for (int i = 0; i < bids.size() - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < bids.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (bids.get(i).getAmount() > bids.get(j).getAmount()) {

                        int temp = bids.get(j).getAmount();
                        bids.set(j, bids.get(i));
                        bids.set(i, temp);   // This line got the error. On set.
                    }
                }
            }
            return bids;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You are trying to `set` an `ArrayList` of type `Bid` to an `integer`, the error is fairly self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
int temp = bids.get(j).getAmount();
```

with

```
Bid temp = bids.get(j);
```

so that types match.